# Read a file and convert to json array

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, file-io

```
array = []

File.open(file.txt) do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    array << line.split.map(&:to_s)
  end
end

puts purgeObject

@test = {
  "strings" => array
}.to_json

puts @test
```

I need strings the output to be the following way. I keep getting an array of arrays i.e. `[["334455"], ["ABC"]]` - what's wrong?

```
{
   "strings" : [
      "334455",
      "ABC"
   ]
}
```

Comment: after your `File.open { .. }`, did you check the output of `array` ?

Comment: This is wrong `array << line.split.map(&)`... where is the method name in `array << line.split.map(&..???)`

Comment: Ah blindness... that's what it was. `array << line.split.map(&:to_s)`. Thanks.

Comment: ok,... now check `puts array` , after the block..

Comment: `Arrays` is good now. `@test` return `[["334455"], ["ABC"]]`

Comment: it shouldn't be... is there any code between `@test = {..}` and `File.open {..}`?

Comment: I updated it with exactly what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do change the line

```
array << line.split.map(&:to_s)
```

to

```
array.concat(line.split.map(&:to_s))
```

Example :

```
array = []
array << [1]
array << [2]
array # => [[1], [2]]
array = []
array.concat([11])
array.concat([12])
array # => [11, 12]
```

Actually [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) outputs as *array of some items*. Thus `line.split.map(&:to_s)` was also giving like `[item1,item2,...]`. Now if you do `array << line.split.map(&:to_s)`, then that `[item1,item2,...]` getting inserted into *array* using [`#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) method. So if you want to insert only `item1,item2,...`, then use [`Array#concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-concat).

You can use [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) method also :

```
array = []
File.foreach(file.txt) do |line|
    array.concat(line.split.map(&:to_s))
end

@test = {
  "strings" => array
}.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

A more ruby way of doing the same thing would be:

```
array = File.readlines('file.txt').flat_map(&:split)

@test = {
  "strings" => array
}.to_json
```

Comment: `readlines` is a nice touch same functionality as mine but cleaner looking +1.

Answer (score 0):

Or why not something like

```
@test = {
  "strings" => File.open("file.txt",&:read).split("\n").flat_map(&:split)
}.to_json
#=> "{\"strings\":[\"this\",\"is\",\"a\",\"test\",\"file\",\"putting\",\"strings\",\"into\",\"an\",\"array\"]}"
JSON.parse(@test)
#=> {"strings"=>["this", "is", "a", "test", "file", "putting", "strings", "into", "an", "array"]}
```